# Fancybox with bootstrap is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery with bootstrap but its not working. Here is a [jsffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/5EV8r/1251/):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ecommerce/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>    <script language="JavaScript" src="http://localhost/ecommerce/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="http://localhost/ecommerce/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".fnybx").fancybox();
            $("body").on("click","a.details",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var _id = $(this).attr("id");
                $("#"+_id).fancybox();
            });
        });
    </script>

   <a href="2_s.jpg" class="fnybx">Click here</a>
```

Comment: seems works in demo fiddle

Comment: its not working in my project

Comment: js error, or load image error?

Comment: When you say,"it's not working" what is happening? When you click on the link does *something* happen? What does it do? If not, does it do anything?

Comment: It takes me to another page to show that picture rather than opening in a fancybox.